# PHP+Mysql Order By Date For Multiple Table ( Via Left Join )

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 table ( `user` and `product` )

I want order rows via date for this tables

> user table :

[image]

> product table :

[image]

> My Code :

```
"SELECT *,product.* FROM `user` LEFT JOIN `product` ORDER BY `?`";
```

I want result it :

Four

One

Three

Two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *appears* that you really want to do a `UNION` query between the `user` and `product` tables.  You can then `SELECT` the `Title` from this result and order using the `Date`.

```
SELECT t.Title
FROM
(
    SELECT Date FROM user
    UNION
    SELECT Date FROM product
) t
ORDER BY t.Date DESC
```